# Access issue with passthrough query in a make table query

Tags: sql, ms-access, teradata, pass-through

I have a passthrough query that runs just like I expect it to.  However, when I use it in a make table query (Access), I'm getting an error message that says "The specified field passThru3.vaulLocation could refer to more than 1 table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL Statement".

The vaultlocation field is made up of fields from a couple of different tables.

The make table query and passthrough query are displayed below.  Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.....

Make Table query:

```
SELECT PassThru3.ItemID, PassThru3.unit, PassThru3.vin, PassThru3.modlYr, PassThru3.make, PassThru3.model, PassThru3.actDate, PassThru3.actUser, PassThru3.groupNbr_branchNbr, PassThru3.vaultLocatiion, PassThru3.br_iorg_id INTO TitleInfo FROM PassThru3;
```

PassThrough Query:

```
SELECT 
tm.title_id as itemID,
v.lgcy_unit_nbr as unit, 
v.vin, 
v.modl_yr_nbr as modlYr, 
v.make_cde as make, 
v.make_modl_dsc as model,  
ta.create_timestamp as actDate, 
ta.user_id as actUser,
--ta.notes as actNotes,
lrd.lgcy_iorg_id as groupNbr_branchNbr,


CASE 

    WHEN vs.vault_req = 0 THEN 'No Vault'  
    WHEN vs.vault_type_id = 2 AND vs.vault_req = 1 THEN (lrd.lgcy_iorg_id || '-' ||  ti.seq_nbr) 
    WHEN vs.vault_type_id = 1 AND vs.vault_req = 1 THEN (tc.cabinet_nbr ||'-' || td.drawer_nbr ||'-' || tf.folder_nbr ||'-' || ts.seq_nbr) 

END as vaultLocation,

tm.br_iorg_id

FROM VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_MASTER tm
join LRD.LRD_IORG lrd on tm.br_iorg_id = lrd.iorg_id
JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.VEH v ON tm.veh_id = v.veh_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.VAULT_SETTINGS vs on tm.br_iorg_id = vs.br_iorg_id  and vs.item_type_id = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_INCREMENTAL ti on tm.title_id = ti.title_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_SEQ ts on tm.title_id = ts.title_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_FOLDER tf on ts.folder_id = tf.folder_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_DRAWER td on tf.drawer_id = td.drawer_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_CABINET tc on td.cabinet_id = tc.cabinet_id 
JOIN VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_ACTIVITY ta ON tm.title_id = ta.title_id AND ta.title_act_id = 
    (select max(title_act_id) from VEH_MGMT_TMS.TITLE_ACTIVITY where title_id = tm.title_id and act_type_id = 1) 
WHERE tm.transit_flag = 0
and ta.create_timestamp >= (current_date  - INTERVAL '3' MONTH)
```

Comment: `PassThru3.vaultLocatiion` - typo or error? Please use your actual code.

Comment: From `||` I assume your backend is Oracle? It might be helpful to add this tag, or at least add it to the question.

Comment: @Andre..........That was the actual code and it was a typo when I wrote it.  Once I corrected the field name, the make table query ran like I expected it to.  I guess I didn't read the error message close enough to spot this issue.  I was hoping another pair of eyes looking at this would help,  Thanks for your help.  The passthrough query uses Teradata and I have updated the tags for that.  Thanks again for all of your help.....

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected a different error message for a non-existing column name. Glad I could help. :)